# Why Spark is running more than one process?

Tags: hadoop, clojure, apache-spark

Recently i have a problem with Spark. I am working on small cluster (4 nodes) and i saw that spark is running (after some more complex calculations) second proccess and its causing some weird problems on this node, for example:

```
5/04/22 08:54:37 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.1 in stage 10.0 (TID 52, hadoop1.itx.pl): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeNoArgInstanceMember(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

I don't know what is the cause of the problem, but when i kill spark worker process and start them again (with one process only) it's working okay until next "cloning".

I have default spark-env settings, so SPARK_WORKERS should be 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second process you're seeing is an executor spawned to process your task. The worker itself only performs coordination duties, one of which is making sure executors are up and running when requested by the driver. This is why the process you're seeing is getting re-spawned.

For a nice overview of the architecture, see [this Spark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html).

The exception you're seeing is most likely caused by classpath issues (missing library, version mismatch between the driver and workers). Specifically, you may have two versions of Clojure on your classpath, similar to [this issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/riemann-users/PtjSMyMBhl4). The missing method was introduced in Clojure 1.6 - see if you're using an older version.

Comment: Fair point, second process is just an executor. I read this doc earlier but miss part about separated processes (somehow).
For the second part i have to check my classpath... ASAP

Comment: You are right about old clojure version, some nodes have pre-installed clojure in version 1.2.